# Got Error 500 when adding to cart Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, http-error-500

I got 500 error when adding products to the shopping cart. I enabled the debug log and got the following error.  I thought it may be caused by affiliate extension. So I disabled the module. But I still got this error. 
[image]

Anyone can help me with this bug? I really appreciate!

Comment: can you refresh one time cache then check and also can you check if there compiler on from admin  ?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module is disabled but it's helper is calling from this observer file:

`app/code/local/MW/Credit/Model/Observer.php` line no 399

Remove helper calling or remove this observer from `app/code/local/MW/etc/config.xml` then your issue would resolve

Comment: hi thank you for your help.  it's resolved.

Comment: Good to hear that. Welcome :)